# SharePoint add-in [SharePoint hosted app in Office 365] Rest api call Cross Origin Resource Sharing error?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, rest, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

When i tired to get list title from developer site present in SharePoint online, i get CROS error. I have provided full permission to list and web in AppManifest.xml;

It is a simple ajax call that consume Sharepoint api rest services

Code:-

```
function ajaxcall() {
    var url1 = "https://xxxlll365.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('xxx')/items?$select=Title";

    $.ajax({

        url: url1,
        dataType: 'json', //tired xml,jsonp, crossdoman:true [no big change]
        cros: true,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
```

Console Error
XMLHttpRequest for https://xxxlll365.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('xxx')/items?$select=Title required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)."Error"

Tired with angularJS and got same error as above !

Answer (score 0):

Here are some detailed articles for your reference:

[WebAPI and CORS enabled REST services](http://wp.sjkp.dk/webapi-and-cors-enabled-rest-services/)

[Cross Site Scripting with SharePoint 2013 REST calls](https://blog.kenaro.com/2014/03/18/cross-site-scripting-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-calls/)

[CORS with sharepoint](https://blog.kenaro.com/2014/03/18/cross-site-scripting-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-calls/)

[CORS SP](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/access-sharepoint-data-from-add-ins-using-the-cross-domain-library)

Answer (score 0):

Try include in the header these options:

"**Control-Allow-Origin**","**https://xxxlll365.sharepoint.com**")

"**Origin**","**https://xxxlll365.sharepoint.com**")